# Android ComponentTest

Tags: android, android-testing

I am writing component tests and would like to separate them in a different buildType.

I created a directory called componentTest in my app root folder and added my test classes

In build.gradle file I added:

```
componentTest.initWith(buildTypes.test)
```

To make my componentTest buildType copy all my test build configurations but I had the following error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'test' for BuildType
```

So, my question is: how to create another test build type?

Comment: What's the purpose of separating into another build type? Is the production code the same for that newly created build type?

Comment: @azizbekian the purpouse is that I am building mocked version of some components for the component tests and I don't want that the unit tests uses this code. I though about separating in packages and making them package protected, but I think that the build type is approach is more correct.